# Change Struct module pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Good day all,  I'd like some help to change a small section in this C program which I have licensed back in the early 90's.   Some of you may be familiar with it,  it's called MajorBBS and as you probably have guess it is bbs software.

In the header file majorbbs.h  we have

```
extern                                                                         
struct module {                    /* module interface block               */  
 char descrp[MNMSIZ];          /*    description for main menu         */  
 int (*lonrou)();              /*    user logon supplemental routine   */  
 int (*sttrou)();              /*    input routine if selected         */  
 void (*stsrou)();             /*    status-input routine if selected  */  
 int (*injrou)();              /*    "injoth" routine for this module  */  
 int (*lofrou)();              /*    user logoff supplemental routine  */  
 void (*huprou)();             /*    hangup (lost carrier) routine     */  
 void (*mcurou)();             /*    midnight cleanup routine          */  
 void (*dlarou)();             /*    delete-account routine            */  
 void (*finrou)();             /*    finish-up (sys shutdown) routine  */  
 } **module;
```

Also in the majorbbs.h we have some code that defines the menu variables

```
extern                                                                              
struct usrmnu {               /* user's menuing-specific variables         */       
 char curpag[PNMSIZ];     /*    current menu page                      */       
 char parpag[PNMSIZ];     /*    parent menu page                       */       
 char selchrs[MAXSEL];    /*    select characters currently available  */       
 char pages[MAXSEL][PNMSIZ]; /* pages or file names for select chars   */       
 char optdsp[MAXSEL];     /*    instructions on how to display options */       
 int keyreq[MAXSEL];      /*    key required for each select character */       
 FILE *fp;                /*    pointer to file currently being viewed */       
 char mnuttl[TITLSZ];     /*    menu page title                        */       
 } *mnuusr;
```

Then in the majorbbs.c file we have

```
struct module module00={      /* module interface block                    */       
 "Menuing System",        /*    description for main menu              */       
 NULL,                    /*    user logon supplemental routine        */       
 mainu,                   /*    input routine if selected              */       
 musthn,                  /*    status-input routine if selected       */       
 NULL,                    /*    "injoth" routine for this module       */       
 NULL,                    /*    user logoff supplemental routine       */       
 loscar,                  /*    hangup (lost carrier) routine          */       
 midnit,                  /*    midnight cleanup routine               */       
 NULL,                    /*    delete-account routine                 */       
 mjrfin                   /*    finish-up (sys shutdown) routine       */       
};
```

What I'd like is to change the value of the descrp here which is defined as "Menuing System" to something more dynamic like the Menu the user is currently on.

From the code here I think it would be mnuusr->curpag which is where the pointer is pointing to I think.

So I'm thinking of a routine.   I am by no means a programmer and I've been there many sites to look for examples of how to do such a thing.  I've searched here for the last couple days (before posting this).   I saw some things 
that sparked a "Hey this might work" but I ended up with compiler errors (more on that in a bit)

What I did was make a routine like

```
char *
mydescrp
{
if (strcmp(module00.descrp,"Menuing System" ) == 0 ) {
    mnuusr=mnuoff(usrnum);
 return(mnuusr->mnuttl);  
} 

}
```

Then if I change the module00 call above to

```
   struct module module00={ 
 mydescrp,   /*  My change */
 NULL,               
 mainu,              
 musthn,             
 NULL,               
 NULL,               
 loscar,             
 midnit,             
 NULL,               
 mjrfin              
  };
```

When I compile I get some error that says:

Initalization not fully bracketed

the list goes on from there.   There are some further initialization later on in majorbbs.c and will gladly supply them if you need.  I am sure one would be.

```
int                                                                 
register_module(                   /* register a module for online use     */       
struct module *mod)                     /* pointer to a module block       */       
 {                                                                                   
 if (strlen(mod->descrp) > MNMSIZ-1) {                                          
      catastro("MODULE NAME \"%s\" TOO LONG!",mod->descrp);                     
 }                                                                              
 if (mod->stsrou == NULL) {                                                     
      mod->stsrou=dfsthn;                                                       
 }                                                                              
 if (nmods == 0) {                                                              
      module=(struct module **)alcmem(sizeof(struct module *));                 
      mdstats=(struct mdstats *)alcmem(sizeof(struct mdstats));                 
 }                                                                              
 else {                                                                         
      module=(struct module **)alcrsz(module,sizeof(struct module *)*nmods,     
                                     sizeof(struct module *)*(nmods+1));        
      mdstats=(struct mdstats *)alcrsz(mdstats,sizeof(struct mdstats)*nmods,    
                                       sizeof(struct mdstats)*(nmods+1));       
 }                                                                              
 module[nmods]=mod;                                                             
 setbtv(mstbb);                                                                 
 if (qeqbtv(mod->descrp,0)) {                                                   
      gcrbtv(&mdstats[nmods],0);                                                
 }                                                                              
 else {                                                                         
      setmem(&mdstats[nmods],sizeof(struct mdstats),0);                         
      strcpy(mdstats[nmods].mdname,mod->descrp);                                
 }                                                                              
 rstbtv();                                                                      
 return(nmods++);                                                               
 }
```

From MENUING.C    mnuoff routine

```
struct usrmnu *
mnuoff(                            /* get pointer to user's menu info      */
int unum)                          /*   user number to grab                */
{
#ifdef PHARLAP
     return((struct usrmnu *)((long)(eclmnubas+(unum<<3))<<16));
#else
     #ifdef ECLIPSE
          return((struct usrmnu *)((long)(eclmnubas+(unum<<3))<<16));
     #else
          return((struct usrmnu *)(muusrs+(unum*(long)sizeof(struct usrmnu))));
     #endif
#endif
}
```

Is this the routine to change for some newly code?  I am simply at a loss on how to go about this.   If you need more code let me know.

I even went as far as asking for help from other majorbbs programmers on usenet but this software is 20 years + old so I don't think anyone uses it anymore let alone modify code anymore.  I would think since it's still C someone might have an idea to help me out.  I am trying to create a new revive with some small modifications.  This being one of two.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Software is not like wine, it does *not* get better when it ages.  This one turned sour at least 15 years ago.  Usually coincides with the author stopping to make changes and not responding to phone calls and email requests anymore.  Much like we'll do.

Comment: I hear what you're saying,  but it's still fun regardless.  :)

Comment: +1 for thinking it is fun. Good attitude, hoping it isn't too lonely.

Comment: "I am by no means a programmer" - without trying to be funny, what you're trying to do is a really bad idea if this is true. The most obvious problems are that both your definition and call of `mydescrp` are missing parameter lists, but honestly, your problems here are likely to only begin once you fix your syntax errors. Any question containing a phrase similar to "I am simply at a loss on how to go about this" is unlikely to be on-topic for Stack Overflow. Good luck, though.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths:   Can you give a brief explanation of how it would be a bad idea?  one thing that comes to my mind would be general protection errors?  maybe?   if that is the case I will take your advice and not pursue this plan.

Comment: @PaulRCulmo: Really just because this wouldn't be a trivial task for an experienced C programmer, who wasn't familiar with this software. For someone who's not a programmer at all, it's going to be practically impossible. For instance, is `module00` a global variable? If so, trying to initialize it with a function call that references another global variable may lead to tears, since the order in which globals are initialized is undefined. In fact, I think you're trying to initialize it in reference to itself, here. There are many, many ways to go horribly wrong in C.

Comment: In other words, you're trying to initialize `module00.descrp` by calling a function which, in its first line, tries to compare the contents of that exact same object, `module00.descrp`, which hasn't been initialized yet, with another string. There's nothing wrong with not knowing things like this, if you're not a C programmer, but if that's true, I don't see how you can really phrase this kind of question in a way that doesn't amount to a request for someone to write the update for you, which wouldn't be an acceptable question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `descrp` field in `struct module` is expecting a `char[]` (or a string), and you're giving it a `char *()` (function returning a string) instead.

Perhaps what you want to do is not call the `mydescrp` function in the declaration of `module00`, but manually perform the check in `register_module`:

```
int register_module(struct module *mod) {
    if (strcmp(mod->descrp, "Menuing System") == 0) {
        struct usrmnu *menu = mnuoff(usrnum);
        // Copy as much of the title to the menu description as possible.
        strncpy(mod->descrp, menu->mnuttl, MNMSIZ-1);
        // Terminate the string in case the title was too long.
        mod->descrp[MNMSIZ-1] = '\0';
    }
    // Rest of method.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but I get a compile error when trying your suggestion.   Lvalue required in function register_module so I think it wants a == which would have no affect right?

Comment: You'd need `strcpy(mod->descrp, mnuusr->mnuttl)`, since `mod->descrp` is a `char` array. You'd need to ensure `MNMSIZ` was greater than or equal to `TITLSZ`, too, to avoid the possibility of overflow, or use `strncpy()` and accept the possibility of truncating the current menu name.

Comment: Thanks all for your suggestions,  it compiles fine now.  However like Paul said earlier my problems are just starting.  When bringing up the system it GP faults.  When I comment out the new code it works fine so hmm maybe I need to put the new code in a new section?

Comment: You can usually find out what is causing the fault using a debugger, but I'd guess that maybe `mnuusr` might not be a valid pointer. What is `usrnum`, and what does the `mnuoff` function do?

Comment: usrnum is the channel number for a particular user,  I will attach the code routine for mnuoff

Comment: Ok I edited my original with the routine for mnuoff.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are assigning the result of `mnuoff(usrnum)` to `mnuusr`? This would overwrite `mnuusr` for the rest of the program (until it changed again). I'm assuming that this probably isn't what you want to do. I've updated the code with regards to this.

Comment: Thanks again Daniel,  but adding that modified code still results in a GP fault. My guess is you would probably need to see the entire code for this which is probably 3 files worth.  The header and two .C files to get the full gist of what's going on.  If you're up for it I can share them with you.  Sorry it's taking so long.

Comment: Unfortunately your account does not have enough reputation to use the chat functionality of StackOverflow. I can have a quick go at fixing this later today, if you e-mail me the files (and any other relevant files such as the makefile). My e-mail address is on my profile page.

Comment: Since we've taken this offline to work on, I'm going to flag it as answered.